# Pegar um elemento de uma classe com Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Quero pegar um elemento HTML que está com uma classe, porém essa mesma classe está em outros elementos.

```
<img class="imagens-noticias" src="imagens-noticias/noticia-1.png" alt="imagem">

<img class="imagens-noticias" src="imagens-noticias/noticia-2.png" alt="imagem">

<img class="imagens-noticias" src="imagens-noticias/noticia-3.png" alt="imagem">
```

Existe a possibilidade de pegar a primeira imagem, sem afetar as outras usando JavaScript puro?

Comment: Sim: `document.querySelector('.imagens-noticias');` pega o primeiro elemento.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim, usando:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".imagens-noticias")[0];
```

Ou:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("imagens-noticias")[0];
```

O `document.querySelectorAll` seleciona todos os elementos que possui a mesma classe criando um *node list* (lista de nós) onde você pode selecionar um pelo seu índice, onde `[0]` é o primeiro, `[1]` é o segundo e assim sucessivamente.

O mesmo comportamento tem o `document.getElementsByClassName`. A diferença entre um e outro é que aquele aceita seletores CSS, que torna muito mais flexível a seleção de elementos ([saiba mais nesta documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)).

Comment: rsrs.. como assim?

Comment: ah tah.... simmm.  tb funciona

Comment: Faltou o All....

Comment: Dá certo tb, mas ao meu ver esse seletor é capenga, porque o interessante é selecionar a coleção. Mas funciona tb. É uma questão de critérios. Eu gosto de selecionar a coleção.

Comment: Se quiser postar uma resposta bacana eu removo a minha, sem problemas.

Comment: Não, eu não iria responder. Por isso comentei rs.

Comment: Pq? Gosta só de comentar? Se quiser responder não tem problema.

Comment: É que eu estava tentando lembrar se já tinha visto uma pergunta semelhante, mas as vezes prefiro olha pra ver se tem algo novo que eu não tenha visto ainda.

Comment: Deu certo!! Brigadão :)